# Mysql Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax

Getting this error if anyone can help?

```
Mysql Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'active = 1' at line 1 Query: SELECT title FROM cms_resorts WHERE ID = 3AND active = 1
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php  
$courseRecords = $db->records('SELECT ID,title FROM '.$dbprefix.'resorts WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY sorting DESC');
for($i=0,$max=count($courseRecords);$i<$max;$i++){

$selected='';
if($validate->value('booking_resort')==$courseRecords[$i]->ID){
    $selected='selected="selected"';
} ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The query in your code sample is not the one erroring. Look at the message: `WHERE ID = 3AND active = 1` You're missing a space before `AND`.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you, I have since found where the missing space was!! I did notice it in the error but was convinced it was a problem in that sample.

Answer (score 4):

Though your sample code doesn't show it, the SQL error has the following in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ID = 3AND active = 1
```

There is no space between `3` and `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

The code and error do not sorrespond to each other.

Code seems to be correct (I assume you don't get `$dbprefix` from client side?).

The error is somewhere where you select only `title` from the table - here you need to add an extra space after ID value:

```
ID = 3AND active = 1
```

should become

```
ID = 3 AND active = 1
```